# @retryable is not triggering the code, what could be the reason?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

I have a spring boot project added these dependecies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

But still it doesnt pick up,

```
@Retryable(value = customeExcep.class, maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1))
private void execute() throws Exception {
    ///logic
    }catch(customeExcep e){
        System.out.println("this exception is thrown "+e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

and application.class has @EnableRetry added.
this method is throwing exception of type customeExcep

Any suggestions??

Comment: The method is `private` so that won't work. Because it cannot be proxied, and the fact that it is `private` also means that it is internally invoked.

Comment: so how to fix it? Yes it is invoked inside the same class.

Comment: It has to be public and will only work if it is an invocation into the object, so you should place it on the outer method (the one that is calling this). Or setup load or compile timeweaving (which in my experience is a bit more difficult).

Comment: Can you give some example? I have a class which has 2 separate methods...1 is caller and other one is the retryable one, which is being called

Answer (score 2):

Spring retry uses AOP to implement the functionality, you need to make the annotated methods public and make sure they are called from outside the object doing the retries. Calling the method with the retryable logic from another method on the same class means the interceptor code doesn't execute, it has to be called from outside for the proxy to work.

Put the retry logic in its own component class, separate from the code that calls it.

Comment: Why does it have to be this way?

Comment: This has nothing to do with avoidance, but is a result of proxy based AOP which is being used. And internal method calls simply don't pass through the proxy.

Comment: ok thanks, I was confused as to why it would need to be in separate file.

Comment: this helped works now.

Answer (score 0):

`@Retryable`, `@Transaction`, `@Cacheable`, etc. are implemented using AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) in Spring Boot. It is implemented through proxy-based weaving. Proxies intercept calls from one bean to another.

1. Retryable function should be public.
2. Recover and Retryable should have same return type.
3. Create retryable methods in different bean instead of calling one retryable method from another retryable method present in same bean as Spring creates proxy objects to handle retrying logic and it cannot create proxy object of itself.